# How to add Hour with sysdate in business hour in Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

Need to adding in  business hours between 9 to 6 ( mean 8 hours daily and exclude Saturday and Sunday; ), now i want to add 40 hours with sysdate date.Need to display finish time,

Suppose i will assign a task on Friday 2nd of May 2014 ,10:30 AM then finish time 
should be Friday 8th of May 2014 ,10:30 AM

Comment: `select start_time + interval '8' hour as finish_time from your_table`